# emacs: Why can't I install auto-complete via package-install?

Tags: emacs

I am new to emacs and have never used package-install before. I am using emacs 24.4 on Windows, but I would like to do the same thing on my emacs installed ona unix server that I ssh into.

These [instructions](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete) say that I can install `auto-complete` with `M-x package-install [RET] auto-complete [RET]`, but when I do this I get `[No match]`. Why is this? How can I install it?

Comment: The package name is `auto-complete`, you are trying to install `autocomplete`. Note the `-`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at what [the instructions](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete#install) say with a little more context:

> ### Install
>
> `auto-complete` is available on [MELPA](http://melpa.org/) and [MELPA-STABLE](http://stable.melpa.org/)
>
> You can install `auto-complete` with the following command.
>
> ```
> M-x package-install [RET] auto-complete [RET]
> ```

Before running the `package-install` you need to [enable MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/getting-started) or MELPA stable:

> Enable installation of packages from MELPA by adding an entry to `package-archives` after `(require 'package)` and before the call to `package-initialize` in your `init.el` or `.emacs` file:
>
> ```
> (require 'package) ;; You might already have this line
> (add-to-list 'package-archives
>              '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
> (when (< emacs-major-version 24)
>   ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
>   (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
> (package-initialize) ;; You might already have this line
> ```
>
> or to add the stable package repository, use this instead of "melpa":
>
> ```
> (add-to-list 'package-archives
>              '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
> ```

You might also need to run `M-x package-refresh-contents` before `M-x package-install` will work. Alternatively, run `M-x package-list-packages` and use the UI provided there, which refreshes contents automatically.

Comment: Still does not seem to be working, even after your suggestions. `M-x package-list-packages` shows me a bunch of packages, but `auto-complete` is not there. The closes thing I see is `auto-overlays`.

Comment: Have you executed the code in my answer, e.g. via `eval-last-sexp` (bound to `C-x C-e` in Emacs Lisp buffers) or by restarting Emacs?

Comment: When I do `M-x package-list-packages` I see a message like `Failed to download Melpa stable-archive` in the buffer.

Comment: OK, fiddled around some more... seems to work now. Auto-complete is now installed ( I see the folders in my .emacs.d folder. I still need to edit my .emacs file to tell emacs to use auto-complete?

Comment: @Fequish, yes, [as documented in the README](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete#basic-configuration) you can have basic support with `(ac-config-default)`. Note that this is a different question to what you asked here, and should really be submitted separately. If you have more questions along these lines please do that instead of asking them in the comments here.

Comment: `package-refresh-contents` is the key. Thx!